# Map and flatMap difference in optional unwrapping in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, dictionary, bind, option-type, flatmap

Both `map` and `flatMap` are defind on `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`, but they differ (obviously) in their definition according to the documentation:

> func map(f: @noescape (T) -> U) -> U!
>
> If self == nil, returns nil. Otherwise, returns f(self!).
>
> func flatMap(f: @noescape (T) -> U!) -> U!
>
> Returns f(self)! iff self and f(self) are not nil.

I tried using them with a simple example:

```
let number: Int? = 1

let res1 = number.map { $0 + 1 }.map { $0 + 1 }
let res2 = number.flatMap { $0 + 1 }.flatMap { $0 + 1 }

res1 //3
res2 //3
```

But they produced the same results even if `number` was `nil.`
So my question is, what is the actual difference between them if I apply `map` or `flatMap` to `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`s? Which one should I choose over the other and when?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(*Remark:* The answer has been updated to reflect the syntax changes in Swift 3 and later, such as the abolishment of `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`.)

[`Optional.map()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) and [`Optional.flatMap()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) are declared as follows (I have omitted the throws/rethrows modifiers which are irrelevant here):

```
func map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) -> U) -> U?
func flatMap<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) -> U?) -> U?
```

Let's consider a simplified version of your first example using “map”:

```
let number: Int? = 1
let res1 = number.map { $0 + 1 }
print(res1) // Optional(2)
```

`number` has the type `Int?` and the closure type is inferred as `(Int) -> Int`. `U` is `Int`, and the type of the return value is `Int?`. `number` is not `nil`, so it is unwrapped and passed `1` is passed to the closure. The closure returns `2` and `map` returns `Optional(2)`. If `number` were `nil` then the result would be `nil`.

Now we consider a simplified version of your second example with “flatMap”:

```
let number: Int? = 1
let res2 = number.flatMap { $0 + 1 }
print(res2) // Optional(2)
```

`flatMap` expects a closure of type `(Wrapped) -> U?`, but `{ $0 + 1 }` does not return an optional. In order to make it compile, the compiler converts this to

```
let res2 = number.flatMap { return Optional($0 + 1) }
```

Now the closure has type `(Int) -> Int?`, and `U` is `Int` again. Again, `number` is unwrapped and passed to the closure. The closure returns `Optional(2)` which is also the return value from `flatMap`. If `number` were `nil` *or* if the closure would return `nil` then the result would be `nil`.

So there is indeed no difference between these invocations:

```
let res1 = number.map { $0 + 1 }
let res2 = number.flatMap { $0 + 1 }
```

However that is not what `flatMap` is meant for. A more realistic example would be

```
func foo(_ s : String?) -> Int? {
    return s.flatMap { Int($0) }
}

print(foo("1")) // Optional(1)
print(foo("x")) // nil (because `Int($0)` returns nil)
print(foo(nil)) // nil (because the argument is nil)
```

Generally, `map` takes a closure of type `(Wrapped) -> U` and transforms

```
Optional<Wrapped>.none          --> Optional<U>.none
Optional<Wrapped>.some(wrapped) --> Optional<U>.some(transform(wrapped))
```

`flatMap` takes a closure of type `(Wrapped) -> U?` and transforms

```
Optional<Wrapped>.none          --> Optional<U>.none
Optional<Wrapped>.some(wrapped) --> transform(wrapped)
```

Here `transform(wrapped)` can be `Optional<U>.none` as well.

If (as in your example) `flatMap` is called with a closure which does *not* return an optional then the compiler converts it to an optional automatically, and there is no difference to `map` anymore.

Comment: It's true, though, that the distinction between `map` and `flatMap` can be difficult to discern because they are not strict about the closure type they take. In many cases they can take the same closure and produce the same result. Maybe `flatMap` should balk if the closure doesn't produce an Optional.

Comment: `Optional.map()` can return `nil` because `U` is a generic type, which can be whatever you want, including an optional.

Comment: @PeterSchorn: Yes, as soon as nested optionals are involved `nil` can mean different things. I have tried to rewrite the answer in order to avoid that ambiguity. Of course `U` can be an optional type as well.

Answer (score 8):

> This is not possible with `map()` where the mapping closure has the signature `(T) -> U`.

That's not quite right. In my view, Martin R's answer doesn't quite get at the heart of the problem, which is that the docs do not correctly describe the difference between `map` and `flatMap`.

The difference is *not* what kind of closure they take. Each will happily accept a closure that produces a nonOptional or a closure that produces an Optional — despite what the docs say, and despite the difference in their declarations. All of these expressions compile:

```
let i : Int? = nil
let result1 = i.map {_ in "hello"} // map, closure produces nonOptional
let result2 = i.flatMap {_ in "hello"} // flatMap, closure produces nonOptional
let result3 = i.map {_ in Optional("hello") } // map, closure produces Optional
let result4 = i.flatMap {_ in Optional("hello") } // flatMap, closure produces Optional
```

Okay, so what's the actual difference? It's what `flatMap` does just in case the closure *does* produce an Optional: it unwraps it, thus preventing a double-wrapped Optional:

```
let i : Int? = nil
let result1 = i.map {_ in "hello"} // String?
let result2 = i.flatMap {_ in "hello"} // String?
let result3 = i.map {_ in Optional("hello") } // String?? // double-wrapped
let result4 = i.flatMap {_ in Optional("hello") } // String? // not double-wrapped
```

That is the *only* difference between map and flatMap.

Comment: I interpret it a bit differently. flatMap takes a closure of type `(T) -> U?`, i.e. the closure always returns an optional. In the second example, the closure `{_ in "hello"}` is converted by the compiler to `{_ in Optional("hello") }`, so that it is the same as the fourth example. In both cases, `Optional("hello")` is returned, there is no unwrapping.

Comment: Yes, `flatMap` doesn't actually unwrap the optional returned by the closure; the difference is that it doesn't wrap result of the closure in another optional, whereas `map` does. This is the fundamental difference between the methods that your answer didn't address.

Answer (score 0):

`flatMap` resolves nested optionals whereas `map` does not.

*flatmap*

```
var temp: Int? = 3
var flag: Bool = false
print(temp.flatMap { $0 < 5 ? 1 : nil } ?? .zero) 

// output: 1
```

*map*

```
var temp: Int? = 3
var flag: Bool = false
print(temp.map { $0 < 5 ? 1 : nil } ?? .zero) 

// output: Optional(Optional(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

[[map vs compactMap vs flatMap]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867208/4770877)

**Swift Optional map vs flatMap**

Let's create our own simple realisation of Optional type and implement `map` and `flatMap` functions

```
enum CustomOptional<T> {
    case none
    case some(T)
    
    public init(_ some: T) {
        self = .some(some)
    }
    
    func map<U>(_ transform: (T) -> U) -> CustomOptional<U> {
        switch self {
        case .some(let value):
            let transformResult: U = transform(value)
            let result: CustomOptional<U> = CustomOptional<U>(transformResult) //<-- force wrap the transformResult
            return result
        case .none:
            return .none
        }
    }
    
    func flatMap<U>(_ transform: (T) -> CustomOptional<U>) -> CustomOptional<U> {
        switch self {
        case .some(let value):
            let transformResult: CustomOptional<U> = transform(value)
            let result: CustomOptional<U> = transformResult
            return result
        case .none:
            return .none
        }
    }
}
```

- `map` - can return Optional Optional
- `flatMap` - can flat Optional Optional to Optional

```
Optional.map { () -> T } -> Optional<T>
Optional.map { () -> Optional<T> } -> Optional<Optional<T>>

Optional.flatMap { () -> Optional<T> } -> Optional<T>
```

`map`: returned value of `transformed` function is wrapped into `Optional` of returned value of `map` function

`flatMap`: returned value of `transformed` function is the same as returned value of `flatMap` function

```
//problem

//T == Int, U == CustomOptional<String>
//map<U>(_ transform: (T) -> U) -> CustomOptional<U>
//map<CustomOptional<String>>(_ transform: (Int) -> CustomOptional<String>) -> CustomOptional<CustomOptional<String>>
let result: CustomOptional<CustomOptional<String>> = CustomOptional(1).map { int in
    return CustomOptional("Hello: \(int)")
}

//solution

//T == Int, U == String
//flatMap<U>(_ transform: (T) -> CustomOptional<U>) -> CustomOptional<U>
//flatMap<U>(_ transform: (Int) -> CustomOptional<String>) -> CustomOptional<String>
let result5: CustomOptional<String> = CustomOptional(1).flatMap { int in
    return CustomOptional("Hello: \(int)")
}
```

[[Swift Functor, Applicative, Monad]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70229530/4770877)