# What is the difference between a Functor and a Monad?

Tags: functional-programming, monads, functor

There are similar questions here but they are attached to a particular programming language and I am looking for an answer on the conceptual level.

As I understand, Functors are essentially immutable containers that expose *map()* API which derives another functor. Which addition makes it possible to call a particular functor a monad?

As I understand, every monad is a functor but not every functor is a monad.

Comment: A functor takes a pure function (and a functorial value) whereas a monad takes a Kleisli arrow, i.e. a function that returns a monad (and a monadic value). Hence you can chain two monads and the second monad can depend on the result of the previous one. You cannot do this with functors.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Formal_definition? The important addition to the Functor API is `flatMap` (or `bind` or `chain` or however you want to call it). If you chose a particular language, it would be easier to explain, as the *purely conceptual* answer is [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)).

Comment: As @Bergi says the simple answer to your question (in the second paragraph) is the presence of a bind/flatMap/chain/whatever (the monadic function).  Assuming your Functor/Monad obeys the monad laws, of course.  But I don't think that is a very helpful *conceptual* answer.  And, it is true that monads are functors because all it takes to transform a monad into a functor is a trivial application of the monadic function to create map/select/etc.

Comment: If your type constructor has no value-level inhabitants, you'll never be able to make a `unit` injection function despite be able to make an admittedly vacuous `map` function. Similar tricks can be played if the type parameter of the type constructor is not used at the term-level.

Comment: In the fairly comprehensive design of my large-scale composable pipeline system, the difference is simple: a monad ***has encapsulated state*** and a functor may not. For systems that compose them together, this entails that functors are therefore (obviously) reusable, while monads ***must be*** single-use. Although functors can consume and emit other functors, in practice, most composed operations emit monads. For example, fan-out involves the functor or monad emitting on a 1:many basis, an operation which, for functors, only makes sense in the context of composing the pipeline itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*(Note that this will be a simplified explanation for category theory concepts)*

#### Functor

A Functor is a function from a set of values a to another set of values: `a -> b`. For a programming language this could be a function that goes from `String -> Integer`:

`function fn(text: string) : integer`

#### Composition

Composition is when you use the value of one function as input to the value of the next: `fa(fb(x))`. For example:

`hash(lowercase(text))`

#### Monads

A Monad allows to compose Functors that either are not composable otherwise, compose Functors by adding extra functionality in the composition, or both.

- An example of the first is a Monad for a Functor `String -> (String, Integer)`
- An example of the second is a Monad that counts the Number of functions called on a value

A Monad includes a Functor `T` that is responsible for the functionality you want plus two other functions:

- `input -> T(input)`
- `T(T(input)) -> T(input)`

The first function allows to transform your input values to a set of values that our Monad can compose. The second function allows for the composition.

So in conclusion, every Monad is not a Functor but uses a Functor to complete it's purpose.

Comment: This definition of functor is strange. I have always read that it's something that can be mapped over, like an optional or a list. In Haskell, it's something that defines `fmap` for this purpose. You're saying that it's any function that maps one type into another. Aren't these definitions incompatible? What am I missing?

Comment: A definition of a Functor in Haskell:
"class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b".

As you see it provides a way to map from f a -> f b. The notion that you can "map over it" is not the definition of a Functor but it's usage outside mathematical scope.

Comment: Ok, I'm very new to all this so I apologize for the ignorance. Just one question more (if it's possible to explain this in a newbie-friendly way), you say a functor is "a function from a set of values a to another set of values" - what's the difference with a function then? Don't all functions map from one set of values (`x`) to another (`f(x)`)? It's probably related with the different types?

Comment: From my understanding a pure function is functor but I am very new to this. If I define a `square x = x * x` 2 will always map to 4. Functors should be composable and I can compose `plus2 x = x + 2` with the square above. that returns me a new functor that I can fmap over `(fmap plus2 square) 4`

Comment: This answer is not quite right.  I was initially confused about this as well.  In the context of computer science, a `Functor` refers to the "data structure" that supports a `map` operation (not just the map function).  The `map` function has a requirement that it takes 1 parameter and returns 1 parameter.  When the input and output types are the same it can also be called an `endofunctor`.

Comment: A functor is a pattern which forces you to implement a map function that returns another functor without changing the original object. In javascript, functors might be arrays, promises, and any other objects with such patterns.

Comment: This definition of functor is indeed very strange. It's sound like a simplified definition of what a function is.

Comment: There are languages that define functors as callable instances of other classes; these functors have nothing to do with the functors of category theory.

Comment: @AlexandrosPanagiotakis The definition of Functor in Haskell that you quoted does not say that a Functor *is* a function, but that a Functor *has* a method (called fmap in this definition). In other words, User was right. Unfortunately, the accepted answer here is wrong.

Answer (score 20):

Let me explain my understanding without going into category theory:

Functors and monads both provide some **tool** to wrapped input, returning a wrapped output.

***Functor*** **= unit + map (i.e. the tool)**

where,

`unit` = something which takes raw input and wraps it inside a small context.

`map` = the tool which takes a function as input, applies it to raw value in wrapper, and returns wrapped result.

Example: Let us define a function which doubles an integer

```
// doubleMe :: Int a -> Int b
const doubleMe = a => 2 * a;
Maybe(2).map(doubleMe)  // Maybe(4)
```

***Monad*** **= unit + flatMap (or bind or chain)**

`flatMap` = the tool which flattens the `map`, as its name implies. It will be clear soon with the example below.

Example: Let us say we have a curried function which appends two strings only if both are not blank.

Let me define one as below:

```
append :: (string a,string b) -> Maybe(string c)
```

Let's now see the problem with `map` (the tool that comes with `Functor`),

```
Maybe("a").map(append("b")) // Maybe(Maybe("ab"))
```

How come there are two `Maybe`s here?

Well, that's what `map` does; it applies the provided function to the wrapped value and wraps the result.

Let's break this into steps,

1. Apply the mapped function to the wrapped value
   ; here the mapped function is `append("b")` and the wrapped value is `"a"`, which results in `Maybe("ab")`.
2. Wrap the result, which returns `Maybe(Maybe("ab"))`.

Now the value we are interested in is wrapped twice. Here comes `flatMap` to the rescue.

```
Maybe("a").flatMap(append("b")) // Maybe("ab")
```

Of course, functors and monads have to follow some other laws too, but I believe this is not in the scope of what is asked.

Comment: Functors do not come with a unit -- they are exactly the things which support `map`.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift Functor, Applicative, Monad**

Functor, Applicative, Monad:

- solve the same problem - working with a wrapped value into context(class)
- using closure[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988242/4770877)
- return a new instance of context(class)

The difference is in parameters of closure

Pseudocode:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    var wrappedValue: T //wrappedValue: - wrapped value
    func foo<U>(function: ???) -> Functor<U> { //function: - function/closure
        //logic
    }
}
```

where ???

```
function: (T) -> U == Functor
function: SomeClass< (T) -> U > == Applicative
function: (T) -> SomeClass<U> == Monad
```

**Functor**

Functor applies a `function` to a `wrapped value`

Pseudocode:

```
class Functor<T> {
    var value: T
    func map<U>(function: (T) -> U) -> Functor<U> {
        return Functor(value: function(value)) //<- apply a function to value
    }
}
```

**Applicative or applicative functor**

Applicative applies `wrapped function` to a `wrapped value`.

The diff with Functor is `wrapped function` instead of `function`

Pseudocode:

```
class Applicative<T> {
    var value: T
    func apply<U>(function: Applicative< (T) -> U >) -> Applicative<U> {
        return Applicative(value: unwrappedFunction(value))
    }
}
```

**Monad**

Monad applies a `function`(which returns a `wrapped value`) to a `wrapped value`

Pseudocode:

```
class Monad<T> {
    var value: T
    func flatMap<U>(function: (T) -> Monad<U>) -> Monad<U> { //function which returns a wrapped value
        return function(value) //applies the function to a wrapped value
    }
}
```

Swift:

- `Optional`, `Collection`, `Result` is Functor and Monad
- `String` is Functor

Optional as an example

```
enum CustomOptional<T> {
    case none
    case some(T)
    
    public init(_ some: T) {
        self = .some(some)
    }
    
    //CustomOptional is Functor
    func map<U>(_ transform: (T) -> U) -> CustomOptional<U> {
        switch self {
        case .some(let value):
            let transformResult: U = transform(value)
            let result: CustomOptional<U> = CustomOptional<U>(transformResult)
            return result
        case .none:
            return .none
        }
    }
    
    //CustomOptional is Applicative
    func apply<U>(transformOptional: CustomOptional<(T) -> U>) -> CustomOptional<U> {
        switch transformOptional {
        case .some(let transform):
            return self.map(transform)
        case .none:
            return .none
        }
    }
    
    //CustomOptional is Monad
    func flatMap<U>(_ transform: (T) -> CustomOptional<U>) -> CustomOptional<U> {
        switch self {
        case .some(let value):
            let transformResult: CustomOptional<U> = transform(value)
            let result: CustomOptional<U> = transformResult
            return result
        case .none:
            return .none
        }
    }
}
```

[[Swift Optional map vs flatMap]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867501/4770877)