# Elegant way to access the value of a record in haskell which is inside a monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, record, pointfree

##### Generalisation of question (read below for specifics to my current problem)

Given a function type definition: `f :: MonadIO m -> a -> m B` where `B` is a custom datatype `B = B {x y z ...}` how can I access a member such as `x` from the value returned by `f`?

##### Problem

I am trying to use the [wave](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wave) package to make an application, but I have a simple problem: I wish to access `waveFileFormat` of the data type `Wave`

However simply doing `waveFileFormat $ readWaveFile "file"` does not work because `readWaveFile "file"` is actually a `MonadIO m => m Wave` returned by [readWaveFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wave-0.2.0/docs/Codec-Audio-Wave.html#v:readWaveFile).

##### What I have tried and does not work

`readWaveFile "file" >>= waveFileFormat`
`readWaveFile "file" >> waveFileFormat`

##### What works (but looks inelegant and horribly long for what it is)

`do{wave<-readWaveFile "file"; return $ waveFileFormat wave}`

---

**This approach however will not work outside a `do` block because of the assignment . It is also extremely long and like boilerplate. How can I avoid this?**

Comment: `readWaveFile "file" >>= waveFileFormat` should have been `readWaveFile "file" >>= return . waveFileFormat`, which is identical to `do{wave<-readWaveFile "file"; return $ waveFileFormat wave}`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Thank you for pointing that out! I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `fmap` (or its infix operator form, `(<$>)`):

```
waveFileFormat <$> readWaveFile "file"
```

This has type `MonadIO m => m WaveFormat`.  You can't ever escape the monad, but you can keep manipulating its value to your heart's content.

Comment: "*You can't ever escape the monad*" - that depends on the monad. Sure, a `MonadIO` monad makes this hard because you can't escape the `IO` monad (without `unsafePerformIO`), but for other monad types it's usually possible. (Not sure how general the OP's question is meant to be)

Comment: Just to clarify, since I am new to the concept of monads, can all monads be considered functors? (For eg, here you use `fmap` which is for functors but for a monad.)

Comment: Never mind, found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252709/what-is-the-difference-between-a-functor-and-a-monad, that answers it.

Comment: @NaitikMundra, all monads are also functors.  Also the answers on that page are ... um ... wrong.

Comment: @luqui could you please elaborate?

Comment: I found this: https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad/, which says "the Applicative typeclass is a superclass of Monad, and the Functor typeclass is a superclass of Applicative. This means that all monads are applicatives, all applicatives are functors, and therefore all monads are also functors."  The haskell wiki is a relaible source, right? So can I trust the info here?

Comment: @Bergi you can't ever escape a monad _polymorphically_.

Comment: @is7s Sure, I was referring to specific monads.

Comment: @NaitikMundra yeah that's correct, and haskellwiki should be generally trustworthy :)