# What is the difference between functor and monad Intuitively

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, functor

I have learned the definitions of functor and monad, But I am still unable to figure out the difference between them except for the definitions. I have read some answers to this problem, In [What is the difference between a Functor and a Monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45252709/15315834) one comment say

> A functor takes a pure function (and a functorial value) whereas a monad takes a Kleisli arrow, i.e. a function that returns a monad (and a monadic value). Hence you can chain two monads and the second monad can depend on the result of the previous one. You cannot do this with functors.

This comment is interesting and gives me a read of their difference. But I still have some questions.

1. why functor cannot use the result of previous one? since `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, when I currying `fmap` with a pure function, I can get a `f a -> f b` function,`f b` depends on `f a`, Does the **result** mean data inside the functor?
2. In category theory I can understand the comment since I cannot get the element in category theory, but In Haskell I find out that I can use the **result** of functor since Haskell can remember the data constructor, Does Haskell prevent me from understanding this comment? Should I understand  this in pure category theory?

Comment: Comparing applicative also helps: `f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. You get this when you apply a pure function to a functor and it expects another argument. Now the functorial structure `f` is outside the pure function, i.e. you don't have access to it but the effect associated with `f` "interferes" with the invocation of the pure function. In case of `Maybe` this means the pure function might never be invoked. Applicative gives you the means to combine two functors (of the same type constructor `f`), but the dependence between them is determined upfront and the overall effect is thus static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, the argument function can never depend on any of the structure from the functor `f` itself; how can it, when all it ever gets passed are `a` values, nothing to do with `f`? When you use `fmap` to get an `f a -> f b` function, the code that is responsible for building the final `f b` value is the code of `fmap` itself, not the code of the `a -> b` function being mapped. The function being mapped might not even be called at all (e.g. if you're using the `Maybe` functor and the `f a` value is `Nothing`, there are no `a` values inside that for `fmap` to pass to the `a -> b` function, and it will never be called).

But `fmap` is fully polymorphic in `a` and `b`, meaning the code of `fmap` doesn't know what those types are and **cannot** assume anything about them. So `fmap` has to build the final `f b` value in a way that only depends on the functor structure added by `f`; the code of `fmap` cannot look at any `a` values and make decisions about what to do. In fact really the **only** thing a lawful `fmap` can do is return a value with exactly the same structure as the input `f a` value, only with any `a`s that were inside replaced by the `b` value returned by the `a -> b` function. That's why you can just `deriving Functor` any data type; there's at most one way to make any given data type a `Functor`, and the compiler can just do it for you.

But the monad `=<<` function<sup>1</sup> has this type: `Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`. Here the mapped function has type `a -> m b`. That means the final `m b` structure returned at the end isn't purely determined by the code of `=<<` (at least not necessarily). The `a -> m b` function **knows what monad is being used** and returns some monadic structure in its `m b` value, not just a raw `b`. The mapped function still doesn't *receive* any monadic structure, so its intermediate `m b` result can't depend on that; any dependency the final `m b` value has on the monadic structure in the original `m a` has to be determined by the code for `=<<` (which again, cannot make any decisions based on `a` values itself). But the mapped function (if it is called) *does* get to contribute some monadic structure, and that **can** depend on the `a` values (because the mapped function doesn't have to be completely polymorphic in `a`; it can inspect `a` values and make decisions based on them).

This means that ultimately *any* part of the final output `m b` might depend on any part of the input (if we don't know what function was mapped, or how the `=<<` function works internally). This is quite different from the functor case, where even without knowing *anything* about the specific functor or the mapped function we know that the final output will always look like "a copy of the input with `a`s replaced by `b`s" (and specifically which `b` replaces each `a` is determined by the mapped function).

---

It's possibly worth noting: almost everything I've said here is a direct consequence of what these types mean:

```
Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Monad m => (a -> m a) -> m a -> m b
```

These aren't special properties of functors and monads you have to remember, it's just a consequence of those operations having those types. (The functor and monad **laws** express things that the types don't, but I've not needed to invoke those to explain this difference)

Once you are really deeply used to thinking about types the Haskell way, you can figure this out for yourself just by looking at the types. I didn't of course; I had it explained to me (a dozen times) when I was learning, and I've remembered it since then. But now I can figure out similar things about new APIs I've never seen before, without any tutorials or explanations.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm using the reversed `=<<` operator rather than the traditional `>>=` operator merely because it lines up better with the `fmap` / `<$>` operator.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I finally realize why we should pattern matching the functorial data `f a`, not for the concrete data inside, but for the `f` structor.

Answer (score 2):

A monad *is* a functor, or rather a functor along with two additional operations. (The original(?) name for a monad was a *triple*.)

It helps to look at the original mathematical definition, which provided an operation `unit :: Monad m => a -> m a`, but instead of `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, defined an operation called `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`, which lets you "remove" a layer of lifting. The two formulations are equivalent, as `join` can be defined in terms of `(>>=)`

```
join ma = ma >>= id
```

and vice versa:

```
ma >>= f = join $ fmap f ma
```

The last definition gives a different interpretation of a monad: it's a functor that you can "compress"; chaining comes for free by mapping a function over an already lifted value, then combining the two layers of lifting back to a single layer.

`unit` is required in either case because there's no way to get a lifted value in the first place with just `fmap`.