# Difference between flatMap and compactMap in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4, swift4.1

It seems like in **Swift 4.1** `flatMap` is deprecated. However there is a new method in **Swift 4.1** `compactMap` which is doing the same thing? 
With `flatMap` you can transform each object in a collection, then remove any items that were nil. 

**Like flatMap**

```
let array = ["1", "2", nil] 
array.flatMap { $0 } // will return "1", "2"
```

**Like compactMap**

```
let array = ["1", "2", nil] 
array.compactMap { $0 } // will return "1", "2"
```

`compactMap` is doing the same thing.

What are the differences between these 2 methods? Why did Apple decide to rename the method?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Swift standard library defines 3 overloads for `flatMap` function:

```
Sequence.flatMap<S>(_: (Element) -> S) -> [S.Element]  
Optional.flatMap<U>(_: (Wrapped) -> U?) -> U?  
Sequence.flatMap<U>(_: (Element) -> U?) -> [U]
```

The last overload function can be misused in two ways:
Consider the following struct and array:

```
struct Person {
  var age: Int
  var name: String
}  

let people = [
  Person(age: 21, name: "Osame"),
  Person(age: 17, name: "Masoud"),
  Person(age: 20, name: "Mehdi")
]
```

**First Way: Additional Wrapping and Unwrapping:**
If you needed to get an array of ages of persons included in `people` array you could use two functions :

```
let flatMappedAges = people.flatMap({$0.age})  // prints: [21, 17, 20]
let mappedAges = people.map({$0.age})  // prints: [21, 17, 20]
```

In this case the `map` function will do the job and there is no need to use `flatMap`, because both produce the same result. Besides, there is a useless wrapping and unwrapping process inside this use case of flatMap.(The closure parameter wraps its returned value with an Optional and the implementation of flatMap unwraps the Optional value before returning it)

**Second Way - String conformance to Collection Protocol:**
Think you need to get a list of persons' name from `people` array. You could use the following line :

```
let names = people.flatMap({$0.name})
```

If you were using a swift version prior to 4.0 you would get a transformed list of

```
["Osame", "Masoud", "Mehdi"]
```

but in newer versions `String` conforms to `Collection` protocol, So, your usage of `flatMap()` would match the first overload function instead of the third one and would give you a flattened result of your transformed values:

```
["O", "s", "a", "m", "e", "M", "a", "s", "o", "u", "d", "M", "e", "h", "d", "i"]
```

**So, How did they solve it? They deprecated third overload of flatMap()**
Because of these misuses, swift team has decided to deprecate the third overload to flatMap function. And their solution to the case where you need to to deal with `Optional`s so far was to introduce a new function called `compactMap()` which will give you the expected result.

Comment: Great explanation! Incidentally, the `let mappedAges = people.map({$0.name})` line is using `$0.name` instead of `$0.age`

Answer (score 20):

There are three different variants of `flatMap`. The variant of `Sequence.flatMap(_:)` that accepts a closure returning an Optional value has been deprecated. Other variants of `flatMap(_:)` on both Sequence and Optional remain as is. The reason as explained in proposal document is because of the misuse.

Deprecated `flatMap` variant functionality is exactly the same under a new method `compactMap`.

See details [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md).

Comment: @Krin-San You missed the point. There are three different variants of flatMap. The  one accepts *Optional Value* has beed deprecated only. So from your example flatMap you are using is different method and is not deprecated. Change you scores to this `let scores:[[Int]?] = [[5,2,7], [4,8], [9,1,3]]` and you will see the deprecated warning and also the same results as you are getting  using 'compactMap'.

Answer (score 0):

**High-order function** - is a function which operates by another function in arguments or/and returned. For example - sort, map, filter, reduce...

**map vs compactMap vs flatMap**

[[RxJava Map vs FlatMap]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67590499/4770877)

- `map` - transform(Optional, Sequence, String)
- `flatMap` - flat difficult structure into a single one(Optional, Collection)
- `compactMap` - next step of flatMap. removes nil

`flatMap` vs `compactMap`

Before Swift v4.1 three realisations of `flatMap` had a place to be(without `compactMap`). That realisation were responsible for removing nil from a sequence. And it were more about `map` than `flatMap`

Experiments

```
//---------------------------------------
//map - for Optional, Sequence, String, Combine
//transform

//Optional
let mapOptional1: Int? = Optional(1).map { $0 } //Optional(1)
let mapOptional2: Int? = Optional(nil).map { $0 } //nil
let mapOptional3: Int?? = Optional(1).map { _ in nil } //Optional(nil)
let mapOptional4: Int?? = Optional(1).map { _ in Optional(nil) } //Optional(nil)

//collection
let mapCollection1: [Int] = [1, 2].map { $0 } //[1, 2]
let mapCollection2: [Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 4].map { $0 } //Optional(1), Optional(2), nil, Optional(4),
let mapCollection3: [Int?] = ["Hello", "1"].map { Int($0) } //[nil, Optional(1)]

//String
let mapString1: [Character] = "Alex".map { $0 } //["A", "l", "e", "x"]




//---------------------------------------
//flatMap - Optional, Collection, Combime

//Optional
let flatMapOptional1: Int? = Optional(1).flatMap { $0 } //Optional(1)
let flatMapOptional2: Int? = Optional(nil).flatMap { $0 } //nil
let flatMapOptional3: Int? = Optional(1).flatMap { _ in nil }
let flatMapOptional4: Int? = Optional(1).flatMap { _ in Optional(nil) }

//Collection
let flatMapCollection1: [Int] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]].flatMap { $0 } //[1, 2, 3, 4]
let flatMapCollection2: [[Int]] = [[1, 2], nil, [3, 4]].flatMap { $0 } //DEPRECATED(use compactMap): [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
let flatMapCollection3: [Int?] = [[1, nil, 2], [3, 4]].flatMap { $0 } //[Optional(1), nil, Optional(2), Optional(3), Optional(4)]
let flatMapCollection4: [Int] = [1, 2].flatMap { $0 } //DEPRECATED(use compactMap):[1, 2]




//---------------------------------------
//compactMap(one of flatMap before 4.1) - Array, Combine
//removes nil from the input array

//Collection
let compactMapCollection1: [Int] = [1, 2, nil, 4].compactMap { $0 } //[1, 2, 4]
let compactMapCollection2: [[Int]] = [[1, 2], nil, [3, 4]].compactMap { $0 } //[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

[[Swift Optional map vs flatMap]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867501/4770877)
[[Swift Functor, Applicative, Monad]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70229530/4770877)